# How to support Bluetooth audio Quickstart in non-Apple apps?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, audio, bluetooth

The Apple Music app seems to have a special feature which allows it to open in the background in response to a Bluetooth audio connection. How can we access this special feature from a third-party app?

## Test setup (before each test case)

1. Acquire a brand new iPhone 7
2. Sign in using your Apple ID
3. Add a song to the music library using iTunes on macOS
4. Delete all apps on the phone
5. Force quit every app on the phone
6. Acquire a brand new 2019 Toyota Camry
7. Use the car to Bluetooth pair with the phone (do not plug into the CarPlay port)
8. Use the phone to disable Bluetooth

## Test case 1

1. Use the phone to enable Bluetooth
2. Use the car to select the Bluetooth audio input

**Result: no song will play**

## Test case 2

1. Download Apple Music through the App Store (don't open it)
2. Use the phone to enable Bluetooth
3. Use the car to select the Bluetooth audio input

**Result: the song will play**

## Test case 3

1. Download VLC through the App Store (don't open it)
2. Use the phone to enable Bluetooth
3. Use the car to select the Bluetooth audio input

**Result: no song will play**

## Discussion

I am working on the VLC for iOS project and we would like to achieve feature parity with Apple Music in this respect. Please advise how we can do this.

Comment: You almost certainly cannot achieve feature parity with Apple Music. Apple Music gets special treatment by Apple. If I downloaded three (non-Apple) audio apps from the App Store, and didn't open any of them, and then performed Test case 3, which app would you expect to receive that treatment? At a minimum, you're going to have to launch VLC by hand at some point.

Comment: Note that in my experience with Bluetooth car audio, the last playing app will generally start playing again automatically on some cars, but not others. (On cars where this happens, I personally find this a very frustrating bug that occurs on a car I own.)